# Transforming into Normal Form

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

There are zones, avatars and instances of zones.  Avatar must belong to zero or one instance for each zone.

```
CREATE TABLE zones (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    name VARCHAR NOT NULL,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE avatars (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE instances (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    zone_id INTEGER REFERENCES zones NOT NULL,
    ...
);

CREATE TABLE avatar_instances (
    avatar_id INTEGER REFERENCES avatars NOT NULL,
    zone_id INTEGER REFERENCES zones NOT NULL,
    instance_id INTEGER REFERENCES instances NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(avatar_id, zone_id)
);
```

I'm not happy with the schema above, because `zone_id` in each record in `avatar_instances` has to agree with the `zone_id` inside of the respective `instances` row.

Ideally I'd like a unique index on avatar_instances which "reaches inside" of the `instances` table to see `instances.zone_id`.

e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE avatar_instances (
    avatar_id INTEGER REFERENCES avatars NOT NULL,
    instance_id INTEGER REFERENCES instances NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(avatar_id, instance.zone_id)
);
```

How can I transform this schema into Nth normal form, while preserving the restriction that 'each avatar must belong to zero or one instance for each zone'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a unique and add a composite FK referencing unique.

```
CREATE TABLE instances (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
    zone_id INTEGER REFERENCES zones NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE (zone_id, id)
);

CREATE TABLE avatar_instances (
    avatar_id INTEGER REFERENCES avatars NOT NULL,
    zone_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    instance_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT fk_ai2i FOREIGN KEY (zone_id, instance_id) REFERENCES instances (zone_id, id),
    PRIMARY KEY(avatar_id, zone_id)
);
```

Allow null in `avatar_instances.instance_id` if Avatar must belong to zero or one instance for each zone.